# Can scripts run even when they are not set as executable?

Tags: scripts

I can seem to run scripts (.sh) with and without them being set as executable. So where exactly this matters?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Let's say you have the file `myscript` containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, World!"
```

If you make this file executable and run it with `./myscript`, then the kernel will see that the first two bytes are `#!`, which means it's a script-file. The kernel will then use the rest of the line as the interpreter, and pass the file as its first argument. So, it runs:

```
/bin/bash myscript
```

and bash reads the file and executes the commands it contains.

Thus, for bash (or whatever interpreter your script requires) to "execute" the script, it only needs to be able to read the file.

So, for scripts, the execute bit just makes it a bit more convenient to execute it. As long as bash is executable, you can always run bash with the script file as argument, or run bash interactively and copy paste the script line by line into your terminal to have the commands executed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. :) If I understood it right, any user access to bash just needs read access to the script to run it because bash will take the script as input and will only need to read it. I can stop this behaviour by taking the read permission of the script for that user. Right? So when does this executable permission is used & exactly matters?

Comment: Yes, if you use "bash myscript" then user only need read access for "myscript" (and of course executable for /bin/bash if bash is there within the path). However, if you make your script executable, things are a bit different. It's true that from the kernel's point of view, it will be "/bin/bash myscript" again if the first line is #!/bin/bash, but to reach that point, first you need to present the script as executable for the user or group. However, that's true if for some user the script is not executable but readable, (s)he can still "run" the script with "bash myscript" ....

Comment: @LGB So that's pretty much useless. Good thing is to cut the read permission away from a user for that script. Right?

Comment: @Ashfame: I would say useful rather than useless. The execute bit on regular files is not (and never was intended to be) used for limiting access. It seems like you're expecting that from it. If you have a binary executable, you must have execute permission on it to run it. However, if you have read access to it, you can always copy the file to your own home directory, in which case the copy will be owned by you, so you can add execute permission to it ... and run it. For directories though, it has a bit different purpose. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Permissions

Comment: What should I use instead of /bin/bash if I don't know the correct interpreter? Is there a command that runs the script according to the shebang line?

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you are not confusing "executing the shell script" with "run a shell script using sh".

This will not be affected by file permissions on `file.sh`:

```
sh file.sh
```

You are executing `sh` (which resolves to the program `/bin/sh`), which reads `file.sh` and executes it's code.

File permissions will have effect if you really *execute the script itself* :

```
./file.sh
```

Note that file permissions are not supported by non-Linux filesystems, like FAT. So even if you run `chmod -x file.sh`, the file will still have it's former permissions.

Execute permission is enforced by the filesystem. But programs can "execute" the code too by reading the file contents, which bypasses filesystem permissions on "execute".

Comment: I understand your point. But then is it for group or world or both?

Comment: @Ashfame If you set the executable permission, the script can be run directly by users who have that permission - whether they have it on a group, world or owner basis. But even people without execute permission can execute it by calling a different program (like `bash`) to do the execution - to block that you would have to take away their `read` permission as well.

Comment: `If you set the executable permission, the script can be run directly by users who have that permission - whether they have it on a group, world or owner basis` But how the permission is granted to different users by checking the executable permission? And I got your second point. You mean taking away their read permission of the script so that they can't even process it through bash. Right?

Comment: @Ashfame On the read permission point, yes. On how, you would call something like `sudo chmod g+x myfile.sh` in the terminal to add execute permissions for the file's group. See [File permissions tutorial](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html). To manage permissions for several users simultaneously, you would use groups, see for example [Managing groups](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html).

Comment: what i meant was when we add the execuatable permission in GUI, then its for whom? owner/group/world?

Comment: I have no nautilus at the moment, but you can try it yourself. Use `stat myfile.sh` after playing with nautlius. The most logical would be `chmod +x myfile.sh`. That is, execute permissions for owner, group and everyone with umask applied.

Answer (score 3):

**The `exec` syscall of the Linux kernel fails with `EACCES` if the file is not executable**

While you can do `sh myprog.sh` (which just reads the files and interprets is), trying to run the program as `./myprog.sh` cannot work, since when you do that:

- your Bash shell on the terminal uses the `exec` system call on `./myprog.sh`
- the shebangs are interpreted directly by the `exec` system call of the Linux kernel as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt/40938801#40938801
- the Linux kernel refuses to execute files without executable permission

This can be verified with `main.c`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char *argv[] = {"myprog", NULL};
    char *envp[] = {NULL};
    int ret;
    ret = execve("myprog.sh", argv, envp);
    perror("execve");
    printf("%d\n", errno);
    printf("%d\n", EACCES);
}
```

and `myprog.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo worked
```

If `myprog.sh` is not executable, `main` fails with:

```
execve: Permission denied
13
13
```

Tested in Ubuntu 17.10, `gcc -std=c99`.

POSIX 7 mentions that at:

> The exec functions, except for fexecve(), shall fail if:
>
> [EACCES]
> Search permission is denied for a directory listed in the new process image file's path prefix, or the new process image file denies execution permission.

Further rationale can be found at: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/unix-execute-permission-can-be-easily-bypassed-is-it-superfluous-or-whats-the

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it in the way that. Can I execute this file? Think of it in the way that: Who can execute this file?

If the computer is yours and the file is yours I am sure you can execute it. You might want to look further into commands like [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown), and file permissions.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I know about them. That means, I (owner) can always execute it. Right? Then setting a file as executable is for the group or world or both?