# Difference between sh file.sh and file.sh

Tags: bash, java

I have two questions :

1. What is the difference between executing `sh filename.sh` and `filename.sh`?
2. How can I make both of them giving me the same output ?

I'm asking this question as right now I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to run a **Java + SWT** application from terminal.

When I do `filename.sh`, it gives me the desired output.
But when I do `sh filename.sh` or `bash filename.sh`, it throws me an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainForm/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainForm.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: MainForm.java.  Program will exit.
```

I know this question is already asked here but I'm still not clear about it.

I have gone through the following links :

[What is the difference between ./ and sh to run a script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script)

[Can scripts run even when they are not set as executable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25681/can-scripts-run-even-when-they-are-not-set-as-executable)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If the script is not too long could you maybe post it? Pastebin is also ok

Answer (score 3):

The script probably knows which shell it should be running in. The first line might be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If you run it with `sh`, the first line (a.k.a. shebang) is ignored. A different shell tries to run the script, but does not understand it - it is like running Java code in Pascal. If you run it with the right shell, it should behave identically:

```
/bin/bash script.sh
```

Comment: Do you mean the 1st line of my filename.sh?

Comment: @RAS: Yes, exactly.

Comment: First line of my filename.sh is `java -classpath .:jars`

Comment: @RAS: Hm... what output do you get if you run `sh filename.sh` in a terminal?

Comment: Exception mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. What do you get from `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: I'm getting : `/bin/bash`

Comment: Does `./filename.sh` work?

Comment: No it doesn't. Gives me the same exception.

Comment: Try `type filename.sh`. You are probably calling a different script.

Comment: output : `filename.sh is hashed (path to filename.sh)`

Comment: And if you run `path to filename.sh`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6139/discussion-between-ras-and-choroba)

Answer (score 1):

By putting `bash` or `sh` before your file, you force to use this shell to execute your file. So it's better to use the first line of the file :

```
#!/path/to/shell
```

So every time you execute your file it will be with the same shell.

And for your second question, no, you need to make a script executable to run it :

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

Comment: You mean giving permission for "Execute : Allow executing file as program" ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GUI, I was talking about a command you have to type in Terminal. But it sounds like the same thing, so give that a try.

Comment: I asked you this as I already have gone through this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file

Comment: That's it. So what's your point ?

Comment: When I do `sh filename.sh` or `bash filename.sh`, it throws me an error.

Comment: If you're referring to the error from the question, it's a Java error. Most likely, you're missing the classpath so it didn't find the main Java class

Comment: But then why it runs successfully when I do `filename.sh` only?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6141/discussion-between-norticus-and-ras)