# How to run Shell script without using chmod?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I wrote a Shell script and named it " process.sh ".
I sent the script to my friend. I am curious if there is a way that he can run the script directly without using `chmod +x process.sh`. For example, he can directly run `./process.sh` after downloading the script.
Do I need to set anything for my script?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: They can run it directly with the shell for which it was written (e.g. `sh process.sh` or `bash process.sh` as appropriate) provided it is *readable* - see for example [Can scripts run even when they are not set as executable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25681/can-scripts-run-even-when-they-are-not-set-as-executable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you "send" the script. If the file permissions are preserved, your friend will be able to run it directly. If not, then the executable bit needs to be set.

As an email attachment, permissions and ownerships are not preserved. Included in for example a `.tar` archive, permissions are preserved when extracting the archive. When using info-zip to create a zip file, permissions also can be preserved.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. After using a zip file, the script can be run without adding chmod after download.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod +x` makes the script executable.

Without it, the file is not executable, and can't be run.